# How can I access properties of private nested class from different assembly?

Tags: c#, properties, nested-class

I have a Class called `SomeFile` which has nested classes called `Header` and `Body`.

I want to access `SomeFile.Header.CreateDate` and `SomeFile.Body.Hash` but the code can't be compiled showing Inconsistent Accessibility error since the nested classes are private and properties of classes in `SomeFile` are public.

I don't want `Header` and `Body` to be instanced outside of `SomeFile` but I want them to be accessed through `SomeFile.Header` and `SomeFile.Body`

Are there any pattern or any solution to achieve this?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your constructors **internal** like this:

```
public class SomeFile
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }

    public Body Body { get; set; }

}

public class Header
{
    internal Header()
    {

    }

    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    internal Body()
    {

    }

    public string Hash { get; private set; }
}
```

This will allow callers to access types such as `Header` and `Body` but they won't be able to instantiate it as requested.

Comment: I tried to change internal to private but it seem like even the outer class can't access nested class private modifier,but this is fair enough for me

Comment: `private` is not required.  `internal` is sufficient to **guarantee compilation** and the requirement _"I don't want Header and Body to be **instanced** outside of SomeFile but I want them to be **accessed** through SomeFile.Header and SomeFile.Body"_.  Thanks for tick